# There is no HTTP_COOKIE key in $_SERVER

Tags: php, tomcat, cookies, httpcookie

I'm using php with tomcat 8.5 My local and prodServer has same configuration. I can see my cookies in browser(with inspect element), but there is no HTTP_COOKIE value in my header and also there is no value in $_COOKIE. All cookie parameters are correct (with expiration, path and domain values). This problem exists in prodServers, in my local everything works correctly.

Where should i look? Cookie path permission or php.ini or tomcat configuration?
Thanks.

Comment: Sounds like something in your server configuration is removing the cookie header before running PHP.

Comment: hi @Barmar you're right. I've tested with apache with same php configuration, all cookies are displayed. When i turned back to tomcat, cookies gone. Could you give some more tips about tomcat configuration about this problem? I have a few experience on tomcat. By the way i'm using tomcat 8.5. I have to use tomcat, i don't have any chance to change it.

Comment: I know nothing about tomcat configuration. Serverfault.com might be a better place to ask about it. You'll need to post the config file if you want help fixing it.